# Change Margins in Forester Package

Tags: ggplot2, dplyr, layout, graphics, margins

Trying to make a forest plot using the forester package. Unfortunately the top margin is too tight and slicing of the headings:

[image]

The package has various "nudge" paramaters, but they are moving individual parts around and messing up alignment.

I really just need to add margins. Have tried using par and mar commands and nothing. Any ideas?

For what it's worth, here's the code:

```
forester(
  left_side_data = full_cox[,c(1,5,6,7)], 
  right_side_data = full_cox[,8],
  estimate = full_cox$`exp(coef)`, 
  ci_low = full_cox$`lower .95`, 
  ci_high = full_cox$`upper .95`, 
  display = TRUE, 
  xlim = c(0.09, 10), 
  null_line_at = 1,  
  x_scale_linear = FALSE, 
  font_family = "sans", 
  stripe_colour = "#eff3f2", 
  justify = c(0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
  )
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?